# How to find and replace between source and destination files (worksheets) in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file of state roster, which looks like this:

```
Abbreviation    Full
AL              Alabama
AK              Alaska
AZ              Arizona
CA              California
```

Then there's a file of state temperature like this:

```
State           Temperature
AK              92
AZ              128
CA              109
```

So there are states in roster but not in the temperature file (`AL`, in this case).

How can I replace the abbreviations in the temperature file with the full names in an automating manner (e.g., a VBA or macro script)? The new temperature file will look like:

```
State           Temperature
Alaska          92
Arizona         128
Florida         109
```

As an expanded consideration, will there be a difference in the programming if now there are states in the temperature file but not in the roster file?

Comment: Q: **How can I replace the abbreviations in the temperature file with the full names in an automating manner ...?** A: *Loop over each item with a `Application.Match`-function to get the full name and then simply set the Value of the looped cell to the value of the cell right to the matched one.* Q: **As an expanded consideration, will there be a difference in the programming if now there are states in the temperature file but not in the roster file?** A: *Yes. You need to cover the case, that there is no match and how to act in that case.*

Answer (score 1):

You could use a formula in the NewTemperature sheet, starting in cell B2 and copy down. No VBA required.

```
=index(Temperature!$B:$B,match(index(StateRoster!$A:$A,Match(A2,StateRoster!$B:$B,0)),Temperature!$A:$A,0))
```